# Connection of the singular value before and after normalization

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues, singular-values

Given a matrix $P \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$, we can get $P = U \Sigma V^T$ by using SVD.

Let's say, we have another matrix $P' \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$, it is the $P$ matrix with normalization along the second dimension. So each row of $P$ is a unit vector. We can also do SVD with $P' = U' \Sigma' V'^T$.

Is there any connection between the singular value $\Sigma$ and $\Sigma'$?

Comment: the matrix $P'$ is related to $P$ by multiplication from the left with a diagonal matrix; that messes up the singular values, there is no simple way to get one set from the other.

Comment: Suppose P were already diagonal. You’re asking if there’s any connection between the entries of an arbitrary diagonal matrix and the entries of the identity matrix.

Comment: Nathaniel Johnston, that is a good point